# How to initialize a PostgreSQL database without running the PostgreSQL server

Tags: database, postgresql, initialization, reliability

In an initialization script, I want to initialize a PostgreSQL directory, but don't need (and don't want) a running PostgreSQL server at this stage.

This would be a no-brainer if I just create the cluster (as user `postgres`):

```
initdb -D ...
```

However, I also need to create the PostgreSQL role, create the database and add some extensions  (also as user `postgres`):

```
createuser someuser
createdb -O someuser somedb
echo 'CREATE EXTENSION xyz;' | psql somedb
```

The latter commands require a running PostgreSQL server. So this whole thing becomes quite messy:

```
initdb -D ...

# Start PostgreSQL server in background
... &

# Wait in a loop until PostgreSQL server is up and running
while ! psql -f /dev/null template1; do
    sleep 0.5
done

createuser someuser
createdb -O someuser somedb
echo 'CREATE EXTENSION xyz;' | psql somedb

# Kill PostgreSQL server
kill ...

# Wait until the process is really killed
sleep 2
```

Especially the part that is waiting for the PostgreSQL server is never 100% reliable. I tried lots of variants and each of them failed in roughly 1 of 20 runs. Also, killing that process may not be 100% reliable in a simple shell script, let alone ensuring that it has stopped correctly.

I believe this is a standard problem that occurs in all use cases involving bootstrapping a server or preparing a VM image. So one would expect that in the year 2016, there should be some existing, realiable tooling for that. So my questions are:

- Is there a simpler and more reliable way to achieve this?
- For example, is there a way to run a PostgreSQL server in some special mode, where just starts up, executes certain SQL commands, and quits immediately after the last SQL command finished?
- As a rough idea, is there something from the internal PostgreSQL test suite can be reused for this purpose?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for [single-user mode](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-postgres.html#APP-POSTGRES-SINGLE-USER).

If you start PostgreSQL like that, you are is a session connected as superuser that waits for SQL statements on standard input.  As soon as you disconnect (with end-of-file), the server process is stopped.

So you could do it like this (with `bash`):

```
postgres --single -D /usr/local/pgsql/data postgres <<-"EOF"
CREATE USER ...;
CREATE DATABASE somedb ...;
EOF

postgres --single -D /usr/local/pgsql/data somedb <<-"EOF"
CREATE EXTENSION ...;
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks! The single-user mode was the missing hint. However, your example code is a bit flawed. It tries to access the database before it was created. It seems that `postgres --single` needs to be executed twice - once with the `postgres` database, then with the created database.

Comment: Of course. `dbname` was just an example. I'll update the answer for more clarity.