# How can I configure a Gitlab-CI service?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I would like to run infrastructure tests in my gitlab-ci pipeline in which a database should be integrated. I would integrate the database as a service.

```
end-to-end-tests:
 image: node:latest
 services:
   - postgres:9.6.19 
 script:
   # fill the database
   # run the tests
```

How can I fill the database with dummy data at the beginning of the tests?

Is it also possible to verify that the initialization of the database was successful?

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40041223/5721620) is what you're looking for?